# TimePicker + CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox, datetimepicker, android-checkbox, android-timepicker

I've got a `TimePicker` in my app and i want to add above it a `CheckBox` that if it checked the `TimePicker` won't work. This is my `TimePicker`: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#TimePicker.

How can I do that? I want the timePicker to look the same as the example.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I will put here the entire project also for others to use it if they ever need it:
Short description: A program that let's you get the time set by user and show it in the bottom of the page, after you press Done button.Used intent to get from one activity to another.

--------Main Activity-------

```
package com.example.chxboxtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button start_intent_button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    start_intent_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_intent_button);
    start_intent_button.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.start_intent_button: {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,TimePickerTest.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
        break;
    }

}

}
```

-------------Main Activity XML-----------------

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >  

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/start_intent_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start Intent Time Picker"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

-------------TimePicker class ---------------

```
  package com.example.chxboxtest;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.CheckBox;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.TimePicker;
 import android.widget.Toast;


 public class TimePickerTest extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private CheckBox cBox;
private TimePicker tPicker;
private TextView showTime;
private Button done;

private String hour;
private String minute;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.time_picker_layout);

    initButtons();
}



private void initButtons() {

    tPicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.time_picker);
    showTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.get_time);
    done = (Button)findViewById(R.id.done);
    cBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.time_picker_checkbox);
    cBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    done.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    //If check enable or disble timePicker
    case R.id.time_picker_checkbox: {

        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "CHECKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tPicker.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NOT CHECKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tPicker.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
        break;

//If Done button pressed get time selected by user

    case R.id.done:{


        tPicker.clearFocus();
        // re-read the values, in my case i put them in a Time object.
        hour   = tPicker.getCurrentHour().toString();
        minute = tPicker.getCurrentMinute().toString();

        if(tPicker.getCurrentMinute().intValue() < 10){

            String setTimeText = hour+ " : " + "0" + minute;
            showTime.setText(setTimeText);
        }else{
            String setTimeText = hour+ " : " + minute;
            showTime.setText(setTimeText);
        }





    }
        break;

    default:
        break;

    }

}

  }
```

-------------TimerPicker XML------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timer_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/time_picker"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/time_picker_checkbox"
    android:text="Check this to Cancel Alarm" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/time_picker_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/time_picker"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/time_picker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/done"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/time_picker"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Done" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/get_time"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Time"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

-------------Manifest.xml-----------

```
     **<activity
        android:name="com.example.chxboxtest.TimePickerTest"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    </activity>**
```

Dont forget to add TimePicker class as activity.
BestPracice add all xml text in strings.xml

Cheers

Comment: Sorry about the time that past but one last thing:
Can you please show me how can i add this into a dialog? Thanks!

Comment: You still remember me?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an functional example with all your requirements.
Tested and 100% functional :)

Put this in xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 >  


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timer_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Check this to Cancel Alarm"
    android:layout_above="@+id/time_picker"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/time_picker_checkbox"
    />

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/time_picker_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/time_picker"
    />

<TimePicker 
    android:id="@+id/time_picker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
```

And Here is your java code:

```
 package com.example.chxboxtest;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.CheckBox;
  import android.widget.TimePicker;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private CheckBox cBox;
private TimePicker tPicker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initButtons();

}

private void initButtons() {

    tPicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.time_picker);

    cBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.time_picker_checkbox);
    cBox.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.time_picker_checkbox: {

        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

      Toast.makeText(this, "Deactivate",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tPicker.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Activate",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tPicker.setEnabled(true);
        }

    }

        break;

    default:
        break;

    }

}

  }
```

If you want this example in a custom dialog please let me know.

Cheers,

Comment: When you create a new project that part will be created by eclipse, You can Ignore this part:)


android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

Comment: ok, i Deleted these lines(it's giving me error).
and i'm getting an error when i try to call that Activity:
http://pastebin.com/27RLUwFT
(I'm calling it by: `startActivity(new Intent(this, TimePickerTest.class));` ) (I called you'r class "TimePickerTest")
thanks!

Comment: Have you added the TimePickerTest in your Manifest.xml ?
I created a project whit your program and added a 
Intent intent = new Intent(this,TimePickerTest.class);
startActivity(intent);

  I will try to send it to you or put it on a fileshare so you can donwnload the whole project :)

Comment: I added, i would like if you try to send me the whole project, that i can see what my problem.Thanks!

Comment: Added on fileshare the project. You can download it and import it after this it will work 100% :) Cheers
Added Link:
http://www.fileshare.ro/e29618784

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but how can i get now which time the user set?(and how can i set the default time).thx

Comment: Addde below the code you need also it will get you the time after you chage it in timepicker and press done button, Have a great day and if you think that this is what you're looking for please select this as the CORECT ANSWER. Thanks